# How do you hotplug-enable new CPU and RAM in a virtual machine?

Tags: server, virtualization, ram, cpu, hotplug

I am running Ubuntu in a virtual machine and I'd like to add CPU and RAM without rebooting the device. How can I hotplug this new virtual hardware?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These can be enabled through the use of the `/sys` filesystem using root credentials.

For the CPU, you change the `0` to a `1` in to the appropriate file of the pattern: `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online`.

For the RAM, you find the state in the files `/sys/devices/system/memory/memory*/state` and change the contents from offline to online.

The script below will turn all CPU and RAM online for you.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Based on script by William Lam - http://engineering.ucsb.edu/~duonglt/vmware/

# Bring CPUs online
for CPU_DIR in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-9]*
do
    CPU=${CPU_DIR##*/}
    echo "Found cpu: '${CPU_DIR}' ..."
    CPU_STATE_FILE="${CPU_DIR}/online"
    if [ -f "${CPU_STATE_FILE}" ]; then
        if grep -qx 1 "${CPU_STATE_FILE}"; then
            echo -e "\t${CPU} already online"
        else
            echo -e "\t${CPU} is new cpu, onlining cpu ..."
            echo 1 > "${CPU_STATE_FILE}"
        fi
    else 
        echo -e "\t${CPU} already configured prior to hot-add"
    fi
done

# Bring all new Memory online
for RAM in $(grep line /sys/devices/system/memory/*/state)
do
    echo "Found ram: ${RAM} ..."
    if [[ "${RAM}" == *":offline" ]]; then
        echo "Bringing online"
        echo $RAM | sed "s/:offline$//"|sed "s/^/echo online > /"|source /dev/stdin
    else
        echo "Already online"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Are you sure you actually have to do this?  I would think that once plugged in, they would be automatically turned on; the ability to turn them off is so you can unplug them, or leave them off to save power.

Comment: Yes, that script was proven necessary, and working.

Comment: I was also expecting Hotplug to work out of the box, but seems like it doesn't ... this is what you need to do, didn't test the script, but manually took care of it, the logic should work. Super Thanx

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thanks. I'm just curios about how do vmware host and guest Linux OS react to this change in number of cores, at the level of NUMA (I know that vmware is quite good to communicate the right NUMA structure at the guest, but I like to know if this change si "acquired". How does this work exactly? Regards

Comment: @FabianoTarlao Are you wanting to know how the NUMA structure results in /sys/devices/system/* occurring? I've got no idea. Sounds like something you could find digging in the kernel code or openvmtools If you find out, let us know. Interesting question.

https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools

Comment: I have written it in my todo list .. for the free-time :-D

Answer (score 6):

Instead of operating the kernel parameters, you can automatically enable hotplugged CPU or memory by using udev rules:

`/etc/udev/rules.d/94-hotplug-cpu-mem.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="cpu", ATTR{online}=="0", ATTR{online}="1"

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="memory", ATTR{state}=="offline", ATTR{state}="online"
```

Tested on CentOS 6/7, Ubuntu 14.

**Debian 7 crashed for unknown reason.** Further testing would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating and keeping script you can run this one line command (it can be also a script if you want).
I have just typed one for memory (one can easyline change this to cpu as well):

```
grep line /sys/devices/system/memory/*/state |grep offline |awk -F '\/' '{print $6}' |while read xx; do echo online >/sys/devices/system/memory/$xx/state ; done
```