# Does libvirt actually do live cpu core allocation to VM?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am using libvirt version 6.0.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS to manage my KVM VMs. I want to change a number of cores of the VM lively using virsh CLI. I have seen that by using `virsh setvcpus VM_name number_of_core --live` I can do this. Here is my output about it from the host OS.

Step 1. I spun up my VM with 1 core. Here is vcpu info of the VM.

```
host$ virsh vcpuinfo ubuntu_18_04_guest4
VCPU:           0
CPU:            14
State:          running
CPU time:       25.8s
CPU Affinity:   yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

2. I change a number of cores of the VM from 1 core to 2 cores.

```
host$ virsh setvcpus ubuntu_18_04_guest4 2 --live
```

3. I check the number of cores of the VM

```
host$ virsh vcpuinfo ubuntu_18_04_guest4
VCPU:           0
CPU:            2
State:          running
CPU time:       65.5s
CPU Affinity:   yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

VCPU:           1
CPU:            0
State:          running
CPU Affinity:   yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

On the host side, it looks like it works. Now, I am moving to the guest OS side. Here is the output when the VM is first spun up with 1 core.
[image]

As we see, there is 1 core because we started the VM with 1 core. Now, I attach the screenshot after I increased the number of cores to 2.
[image]

As we see, I do not see this increase on the guest side although I see it on the host side.
I now reboot the VM.

```
guest$ sudo reboot
```

I attach htop output after rebooting the VM.
[image]

Now previously allocated 2 cores are effective in the guest machine.

To conclude, even if I do live core allocation to VM on the host side, I needed to reboot the VM to make it effective. In this case, what is the reason for the live core allocation?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x86 does not auto-detect for new CPUs, you'd need to tell the guest to set it online. That could be done via: `echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/online`.

Some use a udev rule like `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="cpu", ATTR{online}="1"`  to do this automatically.

There are also limits via the [kernel parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.15/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) `maxcpus` (at boot time) and `smp` which could disable it alltogether. If in doubt have a look at all entries marked `[SMP]` in that document.

After answering I realized that it was [discussed in other questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764620/how-do-you-hotplug-enable-new-cpu-and-ram-in-a-virtual-machine) already, using other terms there, but the same answers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is super helpful. I have one follow-up question. If the libvirt does not tell the guest to set it online, what do they mean by 'live CPU allocation'? Should I run the command you mentioned here from a host over ssh for all guest machines?

Comment: It means that it coordinates with qemu to spawn another vcpu live (without reboot, restart of the guest) - think of inserting an extra CPU into your (virtual) mainboard while running. But that does not mean the guest auto-activates it.